# Format string in ICS Fle (Set font for ICS file)

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook, icalendar

I am Creating ICS file fromC# WPF application and using the following code to generate ICS file.

```
StreamWriter writer;
writer = new StreamWriter(filePath);
writer.WriteLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
writer.WriteLine("VERSION:2.0");
writer.WriteLine("PRODID:MyApp");
writer.WriteLine("CALSCALE:GREGORIAN");
writer.WriteLine("METHOD:PUBLISH");
writer.WriteLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
string startDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(appointmentDetails.StartDate).ToString("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
string endDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(appointmentDetails.EndDate).ToString("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");

writer.WriteLine("DTSTART:" + startDateTime);
writer.WriteLine("DTEND:" + endDateTime);
writer.WriteLine(@"DESCRIPTION:" + appointmentDetails.Body);
writer.WriteLine("SUMMARY:" + appointmentDetails.Subject);
writer.WriteLine("END:VEVENT");
writer.WriteLine("END:VCALENDAR");
writer.Close();
```

But I have some problems while fromating the description.I think when I add \n for new line ,it creates a problem.
I need to format my string like this.

```
------------------
Header1
-----------------
bOdy1
contents
---------------
```

I am using the following line to create a dotted line.

```
result += new String('-', characterLength) + "\\n";
```

But the out put showing one line instead of dotted line.I think “\n” creates the problem.when I add some space after the new line escape character I can see the problem solved.Is there any better/alternate solution for this?

Some string in the description showing in different font style.How can Make it unique?

How can I set the font for this ICs file from the C#?

Please suggest.

Comment: "Have you tried Environment.NewLine instead of \\n?

Comment: Yes I tried.But When I used "Environment.NewLine ",string after that  Environment.NewLine  code disappeared in  the display.So I used \n instead of Environment.NewLine

Answer (score 0):

First: you should try to find an iCalendar library, rather than writing this yourself. The format is very complex, and there's probably a lot of small stuff you're missing.

Every line should be around 75 bytes max. If a line does not fit (because it's bigger) you can split the line by injecting a real newline (`\r\n`) followed by a space or tab.

An iCalendar reader will simply remove any `\r\n[space]` or `\r\n\t`.

You gotta make sure you don't break the file in the middle of a multibyte UTF-8 sequence though.

The value for description must be encoded as such :

- `;` must become `\;`
- `,` must become `\,`
- Any new-line must become a literal `\n` or `\N`

Does that help? If not, please post the full output if your iCalendar stream so I can tell you where you made a mistake.

Answer (score -1):

Format description...

```
    str.AppendLine(String.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", description));
    str.AppendLine(String.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", description));
```